# Build AOSP 5.1 for Sony Xperia Z1 fail

Tags: android, build, android-source, sony-xperia

Many times I tried build AOSP, but I never end it with successfull statement. My host PC is virtual machine Ubuntu 16.04
I tried also a diferent versions of AOSP 6.0, 6.1, 5.0 but every fail. 
Here is screen of part of problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxf3m.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Maybe I am not right described it.
Now lastest messages are:

```
...
libnativehelper/JniConstants.cpp:140: error: unsupported reloc 43
libnativehelper/toStringArray.cpp:21: error: unsupported reloc 43
libnativehelper/toStringArray.cpp:21: error: unsupported reloc 43
...
libnativehelper/JniInvocation.cpp:165: error: unsupported reloc 43
clang: error: linker command failed with error 1
build/core/host_shared_library_internal.mk:44 recipe for target out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libnativehelper.so failed

### make failed with build some targets
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cp /usr/bin/ld.gold prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.11-4.6/x86_64-linux/bin/ld
```

Found the solution here:
[Building Android from sources: unsupported reloc 43](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048358/building-android-from-sources-unsupported-reloc-43)

It worked for me

Comment: Replace the file location by yours. The name is pretty similar, just the version is not the same. Replace your version in the location.