# Error while compiling android source code android-6.0.1_r7

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source, custom-rom

Hello I have latest ubuntu 16.0.4,I am following this tutorial for compiling android source code [source code for android](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading) but I am getting this error
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
build/core/host_shared_library_internal.mk:51: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libart.so' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libart.so] Error 1

I refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048358/building-android-from-sources-unsupported-reloc-43) link but not luck [image]

I have attached the screenshot where I am getting stuck

Comment: have you executed this command  ". build/envsetup.sh" and then "lunch" 
before make ?

Comment: yes i did that but no luck

Comment: i attached this link in my question

Comment: This is not the exact error. you need to scroll a bit upwards, there you can find the errors which occurred during building libartd.so